# jQuery component stop working when routing

Tags: meteor

I'm using Bootstrap Select in Meteor (using this package if relevant: https://github.com/amrali/bootstrap-select-meteor), but everytime I switch page and go back (IronRouter) the select has reverted to a standard HTML select.

I initialize it in the rendered callback but it's only called once and breaks when navigating:

```
Template.temp.rendered = function() {
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
};
```

How can I make sure it's always inited when the template is shown?
I can think of a few hackish ways of solving it but I'm sure there's a better way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen a similar issue, it makes me think that when you are "changing pages" you are not actually "destroying" the template `temp`, as the selectpicker() doesn't get called again when you "change back". You don't show enough information to answer this accurately, but you can try

1. Destroying the selectpicker() during `temp.onDestroyed`
2. Initializing selectpicker() in **every** template you need it for